# x230 tablet , realtek 8192ce connects to router but no internet

Tags: networking, realtek

The issue:

I can ping all devices on the network *except* the gateway (192.168.0.1) and in turn can not access outside of the network without proxying through another device.

The system:

Lenovo x230 Tablet with a Realtek wifi adapter running on Quantal:

Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

The wtf:

I can obtain an IP from the router

```
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr e0:06:e6:c2:d2:e0
inet addr:192.168.0.102 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fec2:d2e0/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:178844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:101517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:121465876 (121.4 MB) TX bytes:10612848 (10.6 MB)
```

I can ping other devices:

```
➜ ~ ping 192.168.0.101
PING 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.101: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=3.84 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.101: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.32 ms
```

I can not ping the gateway:

```
➜ ~ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

My resolv.conf is autogenerated with:

➜ ~ cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search nc.rr.com
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
➜ ~ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 quantal
```

My routing table:

```
➜ ~ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 wlan0
link-local * 255.255.0.0 U 1000 0 0 wlan0
192.168.0.0 * 255.255.255.0 U 9 0 0 wlan0
```

Lastly, my module info for device:

```
➜ ~ modinfo rtl8192ce
filename: /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
firmware: rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
description: Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license: GPL
author: Larry Finger <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author: Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author: lizhaoming <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion: DD4F3D83A75531AC98862F2
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008176sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008177sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008178sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v000010ECd00008191sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends: rtlwifi,mac80211
vermagic: 3.5.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm: swlps:bool
parm: swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
(bool)
parm: ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
(bool)
parm: fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
(bool)
```

Things I've attempted:

Turning off fwlps, ips. Attempted to compile a driver from upstream(realtek.com) and even tried the latest daily mainline kernel for Quantal. Also tried latest compat-wireless and switching out firmware. Tested Windows 7 and verified the card worked. Tested slackware 14, Fedora, Arch and they all exhibit the same issue.

Has anyone seen this before? What really baffles me is that I can not ping the gateway. To verify I can ping the gateway from another system:

```
λ ~ → ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.35 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=5.11 ms
```

This also doesn't happen outside of my network as I was able to use this laptop at UDS-R which kind of points to a router issue but anything without a Realtek adapter works :\

I dont know if any Realtek developers monitor this site but has anyone run into an issue like this?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the relevant bug report is:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902557

@Adam: I have the same setup as you (an X230 with the realtek adapter) and following these instructions fixed the issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902557/comments/166

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.2.0-35-generic.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. When i strace a ping it returns a MSG_NOSIGNAL even though i can ping other devices on the network.

Answer (score 1):

For me changing router to form `802.11bgn` to 802.11bg` solved the problem. Answer found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/483040/12325