# Realtek RTL8188CE desconects randomly and features slow connections

Tags: wireless, realtek

I am brand new to Ubuntu and am having internet issues, as in it disconnects about 10 to 15 minutes in and is generally very slow. I realize this is a very common problem, but it seems like the solutions are dependent on the wireless card and router that you use.  I ran the wireless_script and here is the result:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux sean-ThinkPad-W530 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b2ea Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"****"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=26 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10407   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search san.rr.com

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [****] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192ce
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           18 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    HP-Print-2A-Photosmart 7520: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA2
    Tinonet:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
    bks:             Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA WPA2
    GP_HOME_2:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA
    GP Home:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 84 WPA
    *****:   Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WEP
    2WIRE842:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.108
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             209.18.47.61
    DNS:             209.18.47.62

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"****"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000c71b0ed9c0a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C6C6F7567686C696E686F6D65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD06001018010100
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HP-Print-2A-Photosmart 7520"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000257371c6af
                    Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001B48502D5072696E742D32412D50686F746F736D6172742037353230
                    IE: Unknown: 010802040B0C12161824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A0055010200050039010400580200007B01040058020000330102
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD7708000900040000000701020100020178031650686F746F736D617274203735323020736572696573040F37353235000000000000000F434E330510434E333252334230395630355858000006101C852A4DB8001F08ABCD7446A0D0D52A0704C0A80144080200D4090200080A04000000010B0400000000
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"2WIRE842"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000257353e126
                    Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00083257495245383432
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1B
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:7
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Tinonet"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000004a6bc2c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1568ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000754696E6F6E6574
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030107
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"GP Home"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000559623826ed
                    Extra: Last beacon: 748ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007475020486F6D65
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD09001018020FF0040000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"GP_HOME_2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000005596238218a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 752ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000947505F484F4D455F32
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 05050001005201
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD09001018020FF0040000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### lsmod #####

rtl8192ce              53550  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53172  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              626557  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfwU.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     EF063698748457BBEDB4633
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008176sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008177sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008178sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008191sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,rtl8192c-common,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:3B:EA:01:C4:BD:A9:65:67:CF:A7:23:C9:70:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     9B7F19319428FF0EFE7E350
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:3B:EA:01:C4:BD:A9:65:67:CF:A7:23:C9:70:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     27E91755814596D634B7709
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:3B:EA:01:C4:BD:A9:65:67:CF:A7:23:C9:70:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     32F826C623BC49F764F7974
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:3B:EA:01:C4:BD:A9:65:67:CF:A7:23:C9:70:D8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1502 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8176 (rtl8192ce)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[    5.874716] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   10.734416] rtl8192ce: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[   10.961718] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   10.961864] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   14.594371] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   14.594569] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   16.767585] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   16.787928] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   16.790347] wlan0: authenticated
[   16.790529] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   16.790532] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   16.790534] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   16.791125] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   16.793605] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[   16.793810] wlan0: associated
[   16.793829] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   16.795627] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
[   16.819558] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   16.819648] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   16.825109] wlan0: authenticated
[   16.825226] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   16.825229] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   16.825230] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   16.827130] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   16.831240] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[   16.831377] wlan0: associated
[   26.840359] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[   28.130880] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   28.140931] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   28.184291] wlan0: authenticated
[   28.184410] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   28.184413] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   28.184415] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   28.186558] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   28.294625] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[   28.402693] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[   28.510766] wlan0: association with <MAC address removed> timed out
[   40.803268] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   40.813135] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   40.909274] wlan0: authenticated
[   40.909396] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   40.909399] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   40.909401] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   40.910899] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   40.927199] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[   40.927357] wlan0: associated
[  264.361914] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 7)
[  264.376190] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  264.376344] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  264.381082] wlan0: authenticated
[  264.381342] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  264.381351] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  264.381356] rtl8192ce 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  264.383539] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  264.385799] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[  264.385977] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You're experiencing a very rare problem that I faced too (on moving to Ubuntu 13.10). Please check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453289/internet-disconnects-by-itself-and-never-reconnects-unless-system-restarted/458093#458093). It will help you with your problem. As a note, it doesn't matter what you're using: a WiFi router, wired broadband, or a 3G dongle modem. That solution works for all. If it doesn't help, please add more details and specifications on what you're getting after applying the method.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me (and besides it seems like a very cubersome solution). Perhaps we have a different problem.

Comment: Hmm I see. Maybe you're having another problem, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The driver that your device uses is problematic but sometimes if we add some parameters to it and change some settings in the router we can get it to work if not we will have to compile an new driver.

First in your router change `802.11bgn` to `802.11bg`.

Second change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Third set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Fourth go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

Comment: it works flawlessly now. thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer so other people with the same issue can benefit. Thanks

Comment: For me change to `802.11bg` on the router already fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: did all of this, had to restart, but didn't solve it.

Comment: @Blauhirn ask your own question and post a link to it here and I will look at it. I really need more information on your exact situation to be able to help you.  Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do> Post the output of the script in your question in code tags. Thanks

Comment: as stated in an answer to a similar question to this one, I solved it already: the had to set my resolv.conf to google's DNS only. thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The Realtek drivers (for me the RTL8188ee) are broken from Linux Kernel 3.13 (maybe before) onwards. It seems the kernel developers tried to solve a RTLxxxx driver problem and as a side effect, they broke it. So I guess you have to wait, till someone fix it again. An alternative will be to downgrade to an older kernel version, like the one delivered with Ubuntu LTS 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the [Ubuntu mainline 4.0 kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/) on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 with ASUS PCE-N15and things are much better! `iwconfig` reports 54 Mb/s now instead of 1 Mb/s!

Comment: Switch over to wireless "n only" on your router and it should go up to 150 Mb/s instead of 54.