# Wireless not working 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I have been battling this issue and can not figure it out to save my life. It says I am connected to the Internet, however, I can not access Google or even apt-get update. I have been working through hardwire, just I can not do this when I go back to college. ( The port on my side is broken).

This is the [wireless adapter](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1870/ProductDetail_Download.html).

Tried running make in the driver folder, however it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I have also tried followed this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486350/rtl8192ce-connection-drops-and-fluctuation-on-desktop-with-14-04-64bit-with-enco)

**lspci**

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**-lsmod|grep rtl**

```
lsmod|grep rtl
rtl8192ce              75561  0 
rtl_pci                35587  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                91289  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        70973  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              545325  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              494155  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
compat                 13139  4 cfg80211,mac80211,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
```

PC Specs:

- FX-8320
- GIGABYTE GA-990FXA-UD3
- 650 Ti Boost
- CX 600
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB
- WD 7200 RPM
- Roeswil RNX-N250PCe, Wireless N300 Wi-Fi Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameter of wireless driver as follows and check the reported issuse.

change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg.

change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

IF the issue persists, try compiling new driver. Hope this helps!

Comment: Still doesn't work man.